# How do I read back in the output of Data::Dumper?

Tags: perl, persistence, data-dumper

Let's say I have a text file created using [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), along the lines of:

```
my $x = [ { foo => 'bar', asdf => undef }, 0, -4, [ [] ] ];
```

I'd like to read that file back in and get `$x` back. I tried this:

```
my $vars;
{
  undef $/;
  $vars = <FILE>;
}

eval $vars;
```

But it didn't seem to work -- `$x` not only isn't defined, when I try to use it I get a warning that

> Global symbol $x requires explicit package name.

What's the right way to do this? (And yes, I know it's ugly. It's a quick utility script, not e.g., a life-support system.)

Comment: Data::Dumper isn't really a good choice for storing data.  It's more of a debugging tool.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a thread that provides a couple different options: *[Undumper](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=92509)*

If you're just looking for data persistence the Storable module might be your best bet.

Answer (score 11):

As others have already said, you'd probably be better off storing the data in a better serialisation format:

- [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Storable/) - this is quick and easy, but fairly Perl-specific (but will satisfy your need for a quick solution in a relatively unimportant script easily)
- [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/), using the [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML/) module, or [YAML::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML-Tiny/), or [YAML::Any](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML-Any/) as a wrapper to take advantage of whatever JSON module(s) are available on your system
- [JSON](http://www.json.org/), using the [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON/) module, or [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON-XS/) for more speed (or [JSON::Any](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON-Any/) as a wrapper to take advantage of whatever JSON module(s) are available on your system)
- XML, using the [XML-Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/) module, or one of the other XML modules.

Personally, I think I'd aim for YAML or JSON... you can't get much easier than:

`my $data = YAML::Any::LoadFile($filename);`

Comment: the JSON module now will use JSON::XS by default if it's installed on the system

Answer (score 8):

By default, Data::Dumper output cannot be parsed by eval, especially if the data structure being dumped is circular in some way.  However, you can set

```
$Data::Dumper::Purity = 1;
```

or

```
$obj->Purity(1);
```

where `obj` is a Data::Dumper object.  Either of these will cause Data::Dumper to produce output that can be parsed by eval.

See [the Data::Dumper documenatation at CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyam/Data-Dumper-2.121/Dumper.pm) for all the details.

Answer (score 6):

As Rich says, you probably don't want to use Data::Dumper for persistence, but rather something like **Storable**.

However, to answer the question asked... IIRC, Data::Dumper doesn't declare your variables to be `my`, so are you doing that yourself somehow?

To be able to `eval` the data back in, the variable needs to not be `my` within the eval.  If your text file contained this:

```
$x = [ { foo => 'bar', asdf => undef }, 0, -4, [ [] ] ];
```

Then this would work:

```
my $vars;
{
  undef $/;
  $vars = <FILE>;
}

my $x;    
eval $vars;
print $x;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stay with something easy and human-readable, simply use the [`Data::Dump`](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyam/Data-Dumper-2.121/Dumper.pm) module instead of `Data::Dumper`.  Basically, it is `Data::Dumper` done right -- it produces valid Perl expressions ready for assignment, without creating all those weird `$VAR1`, `$VAR2` etc. variables.

Then, if your code looks like:

```
my $x = [ { foo => 'bar', asdf => undef }, 0, -4, [ [] ] ];
```

Save it using:

```
use Data::Dump "pp";
open F, ">dump.txt";
print F pp($x);
```

This produces a file `dump.txt` that looks like (on my PC at least):

```
[{ asdf => undef, foo => "bar" }, 0, -4, [[]]]
```

Load it using:

```
open F, "dump.txt";
my $vars;
{ local $/ = undef; $vars = <F>; }
my $x = eval $vars;
```

Note that

1. If you're bothering to put the assignment to `$/` in its own block, you should use `local` to ensure it's value is actually restored at the end of the block; and
2. The result of `eval()` needs to be assigned to `$x`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that file was created by Data::Dumper? There shouldn't be a `my` in there.

Some other options are Storable, YAML, or DBM::Deep. I go through some examples in the "Persistence" chapter of [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242/).

Good luck, :)

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is short and worked for me (I was reading in an array).  It takes the filename from the first script argument.

```
# Load in the Dumper'ed library data structure and eval it
my $dsname = $ARGV[0];
my @lib = do "$dsname";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put

```
our $x;
```

into your code before accessing x. That will satisfy the strict error checking.

That being said, I join the other voices in suggesting Storable.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

Writing out:

```
open(my $C, qw{>}, $userdatafile) or croak "$userdatafile: $!";
use Data::Dumper;
print $C Data::Dumper->Dump([\%document], [qw(*document)]);
close($C) || croak "$userdatafile: $!";
```

Reading in:

```
open(my $C, qw{<}, $userdatafile) or croak "$userdatafile: $!";
local $/ = $/;
my $str = <$C>;
close($C) || croak "$userdatafile: $!";
eval { $str };
croak $@ if $@;
```